# Replacing wordpress search with custom code

Tags: search

I'm building a Solr instance in a server and I'd like to replace the wordpress search with it. I tested some Solr-Wordpress plugins but they don't have the flexibility and simplicity I need.

So what I'd like to do is to take the search query from the user and then making an request to the Solr server which will return a list of wp_posts id's. Then I'll pass this list to wp_query and show the user the items.

The code may look like the following:

```
        $url = 'http://{SOLR_IP}:{SOLR_PORT}/solr/{CORE_NAME}/select?indent=on&q={ DESIRED_QUERY }&wt=json';
        $result = file_get_contents($url);
        $data = json_decode($result, true);

        $ids = array();
        foreach ($data['response']['docs'] as $item)
            array_push($ids, $item['id']);


        $args = array(
           'post__in'      => $ids
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

The problem is: I don't know where to put this code in order to replace the original search query in a clean way. I've been looking at both search.php and searchform.php but I don't really know what to do.

Comment: Replace the call to search() in your search.php template to call your solr php instead. Then call your own search field that's linked to your solr logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about my english. I think you must use the build-in query hook to send your posts ids to the main query. It use the [pre_get_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) hook. That will allow you to change the query after it's creation, and before it's execution.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_search_query');
function my_search_query($query) {
    if($query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query() && get_query_var('s', false)) {   
        // Get the "s" query arg from the initial search
        $desired_query = get_query_var('s', false);

        // Your code
        $url = 'http://{SOLR_IP}:{SOLR_PORT}/solr/{CORE_NAME}/select?indent=on&q={ DESIRED_QUERY }&wt=json';
        $result = file_get_contents($url);
        $data = json_decode($result, true);

        $ids = array();
        foreach ($data['response']['docs'] as $item)
        {
            array_push($ids, $item['id']);          
        }

        // Update the main query
        $query->set('post__in' => $ids);
    }
    return $query;
}
```

You will update the main query with your new ids from your Solr system.
There is probably better ways to get the search query like using `get_search_query` but I'm not sure that this function is defined during `pre_get_posts` hook.